# Runtime error can not start new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tcp, python-multithreading

I am trying to check if data is available on one port. If this it is avaiable then a message "yes" should be sent to another port and "no" if there is no data. 
A client is connecting to that port where "yes" or "no" is coming. I run the script and every thing looked fine. But after one hour I got the error: 
Runtime error can not start new thread. Exception in Thread 11:
Traceback< most recent call last: file threading.py line 914 in boot strap-inner.

I am new to python and I really do not understand what is going on. My code contains many threads as I am checking data from 10 ports and sending "yes" or "no" message to other 10 ports. 
Here is a part of my code for 1 port:

```
    import time
import socket
import threading
from threading import Thread
import select

#-----------------------------------Server --------------------------
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET) #Socket
h = '127.0.0.1' #Host where data coming from
p = 14201 #Port
halarm = "127.0.0.1" # A port will be opened to send availabilty status
palarm = 14202 # Port
def Server ():
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            s.connect((h, p))
        except socket.error:
            pass

#-----------------------------------Server/Client -------------------------------
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((halarm, palarm)) # Bind to the Port where
sock.listen(1)        
def func(conn): # Server-Client Function 
    while True:
        try:
            global s
            Timeout = select.select([s], [], [], 5)# Timeout in seconds
            connected = True
            while True:

                try:
                    if Timeout[0]:
                        conn.send(bytes("yes", "utf-8"))
                        time.sleep(3)
                    else:
                        conn.send(bytes("no", "utf-8"))
                        time.sleep(3)
                    newConnection= False
                    while not newConnection:
                        try:
                            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
                            s.connect((h, p))
                            Timeout = select.select([s], [], [], 5)# Timeout in seconds
                            newConnection= True
                        except socket.error:
                            conn.send(bytes("Port is closed", "utf-8"))                            
                            time.sleep(3)
                            pass
                except socket.error:
                    pass
        except:
            pass
def connThread():
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        Thread(target = func, args=(conn,)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = Server).start()
    Thread(target = connThread).start()
```

How can I solve this problem ? I appreciate all your help.

Comment: You're probably exhausting system resources. You keep creating threads but they never end. Try monitoring your program from *taskmgr*. Also `connThread` and `Server` names should be switched.

Comment: I am keep watching it. CPU Utilization from my program is 30 % and 60% in total.

Comment: Is there any solution for that? I am just trying to keep connection with the client who is connecting to the port where "yes" and "no" are sent to. If I did not use thread, then it will not be possible to have an active check each 10 seconds for example. Because otherwise a socket timeout will appear

Comment: *Python* threads don't take up *CPU*. Try monitoring memory and threads.Also once a socket is connected can't be connected again. `except: pass` is a bad pattern (especially if you don't know your way). Try printing smth, and you'll probably get lot of output.